# PHP - Best way to use above directory includes

Tags: php, include, include-path

I'm having some problems with some parts of my website are accessing some files from different roots and the includes end sometimes like this:

```
require_once ('../eggs/libs/lagger/lagger_config.php');
require_once ('../eggs/libs/lagger/lagger_init.php');
```

and sometimes like this:

```
require_once("../libs/lagger/lagger_config.php");
require_once("../libs/lagger/lagger_init.php");
```

is there a better way to solve this problem, without having to use the:

```
../../
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to get the base directory, i.e.

```
define("ROOT",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
define("LAGGER",ROOT."/lagger/"):
```

then:

```
require_once(LAGGER."lagger_config.php");
require_once(LAGGER."lagger_init.php");
```

P.s. I suggest this as you can then use ROOT to build up paths that will be consistent.

Comment: I used like this and worked fine. I created a configpath.php where i keep my path constants. I just have one doubt, are there any security issues if i start to use like this in the other files:
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'eggs/config/configpath.php');
Or can i use like that without any problem?

Comment: yip, you can use it that way perfectly well.. i just like to define it as ROOT or other things- it just helps make code more readable.

Comment: Security risk, minimal, DOCUMENT_ROOT (and $_SERVER) is defined entirely server side, and it is not vulnerable to browser-based attacks. Put it this way I use it on extremely busy commercial sites.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a file that gets run for every request (like a front controller) you can do something like this:

```
define('APP_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Then, in your individual scripts:

```
require_once APP_PATH . '/library/whatever.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set_include_path('../eggs/libs/lagger/');

require_once("lagger_config.php");
require_once("lagger_init.php");
```

The only benefit to this is you can use `../` only once, instead of with every include.  However, when the amount of `../` changes, you'll still need to declare the appropriate path.

On the other hand, if your script has access to the root directory, you can define the include path as `{root}/eggs/libs/lagger/` (where {root} is the path to the root) and just set it once, without using relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths, like you're doing, are the standard way of including files like you are.

If you dislike that, I've a few projects where I define the 'INCLUDES_FOLDER' to the absolute path.

So your includes would become

```
require_once(INCLUDES_FOLDER."/libs/lagger/lagger_config.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_FOLDER."/libs/lagger/lagger_init.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's either this or set absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ':/path/to/eggs/libs'));
```

Putting this at the top of the script, before you do any includes, will save you having to do the paths in each include/require call.

Alternatively you can modify the `include_path` at the php.ini level so it's permanent for all scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can defined some constants you can use throughout your website:

```
<?php

   define("ABS_PATH", '../');
   define("DBL_ABS_PATH", '../../');

   //used in code:

   require_once (ABS_PATH.'eggs/libs/lagger/lagger_config.php');
   //and:
   require_once(DBL_ABS_PATH."libs/lagger/lagger_init.php");

?>
```